# Customising the look of the asp.net calendar

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, calendar

I'd like to change the asp.net calendar to display one single week, without displaying hours. The end result will hopefully look something like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you got some example code to go with this? It's certainly possible, but without knowing what part you're stuck on, it's difficult to help.

Comment: @Lion I actually don't. I can't find anything in the documentation other than width and height, I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: @Lion of course, the suggestion may be to simply create an HTML control of my own, however I was hoping to use the asp.net tool alongside EWS.

Comment: If you really want something that looks like that, I'd definitely not try to use the calendar control. The calendar control is overkill for what is essentially a table with two rows.

Comment: @DanielCook That's what I'm now trying to create.

Comment: Since you're using WebForms, have you tried daypilot.org?